# How to download PowerShell 3.0 on Windows 7 32bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, download, powershell

Microsoft.com wants me to update to SP1 on Windows7 , but I can't do that because it will mess up other installed softwares.

How and where can I just install PowerShell 3.0 .
I ready have PowerShell 2.0 preinstalled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell 3.0 on Windows 7 requires Service Pack 1.  You can see the system requirements on the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=34595#system-requirements).

Comment: I just checked, I already have SP1 installed, and that Link only had 64bit and up, nothing for 32bit.

Comment: @mowgli: 32-bit link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/6/E76850B8-DA6E-4FF5-8CCE-A24FC513FD16/Windows6.1-KB2506143-x86.msu

Comment: Windows XP not supported